# how to get startOffset of File as getting in AssetFileDescriptor

Tags: java, android, file

I am using AssetFileDescriptor for getting StartOffset by calling getStartOffset which I have placed in app raw / assets folder.

How can I get similar startOffset using File object for the files which are not in assets / raw folder? but in downloaded in the app store and have a file object for it.

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd0 = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.lycka);
AssetFileDescriptor fd1 = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.nuyorica);

fileAoffset = (int)fd0.getStartOffset();
fileAlength = (int)fd0.getLength();
fileBoffset = (int)fd1.getStartOffset();
fileBlength = (int)fd1.getLength();

File file = new File("data/user/0/com.myapp.com/files/audio/-LGHK12NDo83k9pHakIZ.m4a");
long fileLen = file.length();
// i want startOffset from File object as getting in AssetFileDescriptor
```

Comment: agree, I need it for using it in c++ code. I am getting using AssetFileDescriptor.
but not sure how to get for files which are not in the assets folder but in-app storage as in code.

Comment: I am using superpowered for audio processing and analyze.
I need to pass into superpowered constructor. https://jmp.sh/wPkUWKj and https://jmp.sh/v8tboKn

just now i got the answer, i'll post it here.
thank you very much for your time and interaction

Answer (score 0):

If you want StartOffset using file path you can use bellow code

```
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try {
        AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
        afd = manager.openNonAssetFd(fileName);
        return new long[] { afd.getParcelFileDescriptor().detachFd(),
                            afd.getStartOffset(),
                            afd.getLength() };
    } catch (IOException e) {

        if (!e.getMessage().equals("") && !e.getMessage().equals(fileName)) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error while loading asset " + fileName + ": " + e);
        }
        return new long[] {-1, -1, -1};
    }
```